# how can I parameterize select function in scandir

Tags: c++, c, parameters, scandir

The scandir() function scans the directory dir, calling
select() on each directory entry as "int(*filter)(const struct dirent *)"
How can I pass pattern value as parameter to fnmatch(const char *pattern, const char *string, int flags) function used in filter ?

Here my sample code

```
int my_selectgrf(const struct dirent *namelist)
{
   int  r = 0;
   char     my_pattern[] = "*.grf";
   r = fnmatch(my_pattern, namelist->d_name, FNM_PERIOD);

   return (r==0)?1:0;
}
scandir("/pub/data/grf", &namelist, my_selectgrf, alphasort);
```

my goal is to be able to use my_pattern as input parameter.

Comment: What happens when you do what you show in your code? Do you get compilation errors? Runtime errors? It doesn't work as expected (in which case, what's the actual and expected results?)

Comment: `my_pattern` or `pattern`?

Comment: my_pattern, I'm sorry I have corrected the code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer: You can't. This is an atrociously bad API, and it's outright shameful that something like this was added to POSIX as recently as 2008 (based on a bad design in glibc). This kind of API without a way to parameterize it or pass it a context should have been abolished 20+ years ago.

With that said, there are some workarounds:

Approach 1: Use a global variable, and if your code needs to be thread-safe, ensure that only one thread can be using `scandir` with the given scan function at a time, by locking. This of course *serializes* usage, which is probably not acceptable if you actually want to be calling the function from multiple threads.

Approach 2: Use thread-local storage, either the GCC `__thread` keyword (or the C11 `_Thread_local` keyword, which GCC sadly still does not accept) or POSIX `pthread_setspecific` and family. This is fairly clean, but unfortunately it may not be correct; if the implementation of `scandir` internally used multiple threads, the parameter could fail to be available in some calls back to the scan function. At present, I don't believe there are multi-threaded implementations of `scandir`.

Now, the better solution:

Ditch `scandir` and write your own function to do the same thing, with the proper API. It's only a few lines anyway.

Comment: It's exactly what I was writing... +1 for you. I'd add also that there may be reentrancy problems when Unix signals are involved, in particular with old-stile signal API. Too bad!

Comment: @R.. Thanks for your suggestion, where can I find the source code for scandir?

Comment: The glibc source for scandir is here: [http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/glibc/dirent/scandirat.c]. Please note that for portable code (i.e., non-glibc targets), you should replace the readdir() call with readdir_r() (and take all prudent readdir_r() precautions).

Comment: `readdir_r` is aactually being deprecated because it's not safe on systems with no `NAME_MAX`. Use `readdir`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to make your `my_selectgrf` function a nested function which then accesses your local function parameter. It's very clean with no added source code complexity but unfortunately it opens up a whole stack of problems (pun intended). Some compilers won't do it, Java will refuse if you write a JNI for it, etc...