# scandir filter by substring

Tags: c, linux, filter, substring, scandir

I am trying to filter a `scandir` by substrings. I have my function working but just with a predetermined string.

```
int nameFilter(const struct dirent *entry) {
    if (strstr(entry->d_name, "example") != NULL)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

But I can't find a way where I can filter an `argv[i]` because there is no way I can declare it.

```
int (*filter)(const struct dirent *)
```

Do you guys know any solution?

Comment: So I found the answer here: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780788/how-can-i-parameterize-select-function-in-scandir).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to use a global variable, with all bad side-effects if used in a threaded environment or from a signal handler:

```
static const char *global_filter_name;

int nameFilter(const struct dirent *entry) {
    return strstr(entry->d_name, global_filter_name) != NULL;
}
```

and set `global_filter_name` before calling `scandir`.

Comment: Yes. I found and answer here: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780788/how-can-i-parameterize-select-function-in-scandir). Anyway thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

Your function does not risk recursion, so:

You can use a static-storage-duration or thread-storage-duration object for additional context:

```
/* At file scope */
static const char ** filter_names;

/* ... */

/*
 * Prior to being invoked, populate filter_names
 * with a pointer into an array of pointers to strings,
 * with a null pointer sentinel value at the end
 */
int nameFilter(const struct dirent *entry){
    const char ** filter;

    for (filter = filter_names; *filter; ++filter) {
        if(strstr(entry->d_name,*filter) != NULL)
            return 1;
      }
    /* chqrlie correction */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see what you did. Anyway I just need an `argv[]` parameter but this would definitely works. Thank you.

Comment: Move the `return 0;` out of the `for` loop body.